# How remove specific unigram from the text corpus but still maintaining the Bi-grams of that word?

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, nlp, nltk, n-gram

I have  situation where I  have to remove a specific words unigram from text corpus while maintaining bi-grams  of that word along with unigrams of that word.

I am  trying to pass a text  address data ( column in a excel) along with some other numerical features  to a classification algorithm. I need to countvectorize the text data and filter out specific uni-grams and attach them back to the dataframe so that classifier algorithm can understand it.

```
** sample data in Text Column**

TAJ MAHAL
TAJ MALABAR KOCHI
TAJ MALABAR KOCHI
TAJ  RESIDENCY  TVM
LEELA PALACE  
PALACE  ROAD
HILL VIEW ROAD
HILL  AVENUE
HILL STATION
```

**For Taj and Hill ,I want only Bigrams and trigrams ,rest all words i want unigram,bigrams and trigrams.**

**OUTPUT BIGRAM and UNIGRAM **

```
TAJ MAHAL
TAJ MALABAR 
MALABAR KOCHI
TAJ  RESIDENCY 
KOCHI
LEELA 
PALACE  
LEELA PALACE  
PALACE  ROAD
HILL VIEW
HILL  AVENUE
HILL STATION
```

**When I try use stopwords as Taj and Hill , the bigrams and trigrams are also not generated**

```
  cv = CountVectorizer( max_features = 200,analyzer='word',ngram_range=(1, 3))
    cv_txt = cv.fit_transform(data.pop('Txt'))
   for i, col in enumerate(cv.get_feature_names()):
    data[col] = pd.SparseSeries(cv_txt[:, i].toarray().ravel(), fill_value=0)
```

**After filtering out the specific unigrams , i want attach them back to the dataframe  so that I can run a classification algorithm.
Final output is sparse matrix of countvectorized text data**

Comment: use `ngram_range=(2,3)`

Comment: @vivek-kumar I'm guessing OP wanted to remove specific unigrams but keep unigrams in general.

Comment: @ncfirth, correct. Also I want attach the elements after filtering from countvectorizer back to the data frame.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to remove the specific unigrams then you will have to remove them from the transformed data using a mask. If this is going to be used in anything more complicated than a one off analysis I would suggest writing a wrapper class to manage it otherwise it will become difficult to keep track.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
import pandas as pd

X = """TAJ MAHAL
TAJ MALABAR KOCHI
TAJ MALABAR KOCHI
TAJ  RESIDENCY  TVM
LEELA PALACE  
PALACE  ROAD
HILL VIEW ROAD
HILL  AVENUE
HILL STATION"""
X = X.split('\n')
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(txt=X))

cv = CountVectorizer(max_features = 200, analyzer='word', ngram_range=(1, 3))
cv.fit(df.txt)
feat_name = cv.get_feature_names()

#List of unigrams to remove (will work for ngrams too)
remove_list = ['taj', 'hill']

# This is the mask of features you want to keep
keep_mask = ~np.in1d(feat_name, remove_list)

# before the mask
X_transformed = cv.transform(df.txt)
print(X_transformed.shape)

# after the mask
X_transformed = X_transformed[:, keep_mask]
print(X_transformed.shape)
```

**EDIT to updated question**

```
# code to do the pandas merge
feat_name = np.array(feat_name)[keep_mask]
df_2 = pd.SparseDataFrame(data=X_transformed,
                          columns=feat_name,
                          default_fill_value=0)
df_merge = df.merge(df_2, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

**Output:**

```
(9, 13)
(9, 11)
```

To get this in one neat dataframe, just a

Comment: I want to attach this back to dataframe as well , how that can be done
for i, col in enumerate(cv.get_feature_names()):
    data[col] = pd.SparseSeries(cv_addr[:, i].toarray().ravel(), fill_value=0)

Comment: Can you edit your question to make it clear exactly what type of data input and output you expect please?

Comment: I have updated the question with more information, attached a piece of my code as well

Comment: Can you mark the answer as correct if that fully answer your question.